# Why do I get Error 0x80070057 - "The Parameter is Incorrect" when restoring from Windows Backup?

Tags: windows-7, backup, restore

I have a backup of my pc done with normal windows7 backup tool and i'm trying to restore it to  a new ssd.
To be clear, i have an install disk and i want to restore the image.
I always get that error. Back ups were regular and i have more than one image to choose from so it shouldn't be a corrupt backup
I've read this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982736 but it's more backup related, ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request this hotfix va email (click on the green button) and install it on your Windows 7:

**Restore operation by using Backup and Restore may fail in Windows 7 SP1**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2569601/

> Assume that you try to restore files or system backups by using Backup
>   and Restore in Control Panel on a computer that is running Windows 7
>   Service Pack 1 (SP1). In this situation, the restore operation may
>   fail.
>
> **System Restore** System Restore did not complete successfully. Your computer's system files and settings were not changed.
>
> **Details:** System Restore failed while scanning the file system on the drive C:. The drive might be corrupt. You might want to retry
>   System Restore after running chkdsk /R on this disk. An unspecified
>   error occurred during System Restore. (0x80070057) You can try System
>   Restore again and choose a different restore point. If you continue to
>   see this error, you can try an advanced recovery method. For more
>   information, see What is Recovery?

Comment: I'm trying to restore a backup from an install disk, not from an already installed version

Comment: integrate the Update into a Window DVD with DISM.

Comment: ok, so i downloaded the hotfix. it's an exe file. Where do i download DISM?

Comment: run the Exe, it extracts the MSU file. DISM is already part of Windows 7. http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/11/20/3387485.aspx

Comment: In the end i simply created a dvd for recovery from another win 7 installation and finally got my backup working which has been easier and didn't present the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2007/06/22/common-causes-and-solutions-to-backup-system-restore-and-complete-pc-backup-problems.aspx

It says:

**Error or Symptom:**
*File Backup fails with the following error: The parameter is incorrect. (0x80070057)*

**Cause/Solution:**
*This error is caused by a bug in File Backup where if you don't back up at least one file during the full backup, every backup after that fails. The workaround is to go through the Backup wizard again and choose a new full file backup at the very end.*

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is not during backup, it's during restore. All backups were succesful

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue while trying to restore a backup created with Windows 7. I was using a usb stick with [an official Windows recovery disk](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38435) on it. It correctly finds my backup image and I can start the restore process, but shortly after I get the error mentioned in the first post.

The solution:
At the screen where you can exclude partition, pull out the usb stick (or remove the CD/DVD). The process is loaded into ram, so everything will continue to work - and miraculously, the error does not come up.
I also changed the volume label of the partition where the backup is placed from "C" to "G" (or something other high) using diskpart. Doing this without unplugging the usb is not sufficient, the error still occurs. If both are necessary I cannot say as I never tried it without changing the label.

Thanks to Guenter Born at borncity.de for a [great troubleshooting article](http://www.borncity.com/blog/2014/06/16/troubleshoothing-windows-backup-fehler-0x80070057-teil-1/) (German).

My personal conclusion:
Never ever use any windows tool when your data or time is at stakes. It does not even work when you are doing it completely the windows way (create and restore windows system with windows utilities). There are great (bootable) system backup tools out there, the time needed for choosing and getting to know one is well invested.