# Win7 Image Restore Woes

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, backup

I have an internal disk with a brand new Windows 7 installation and another disk with a Win7 image backup I made before another drive croaked.  I use a USB stick to boot into the recovery mode because the CDROM/DVD on the computer is dead.

When I boot from the USB and try a restore, I get a 0x80070057 error.  I read some online posts that talked about regional settings and adding a registry entry.  I couldn't do this to the USB, so I made them to the new Win7 installation and booted it into recovery.

The problem is that the recovery process wants to make a CD and the drive doesn't work so the restore keeps bombing.

Is there any way to do a Win7 restore and bypass this step to create a CD?  It seems like I either (1) need to get a new CD/DVD drive or (2) figure out why the USB recovery is throwing the error?

Comment: You may think you were specific, but can you be more specific about what steps you are taking and exactly what you are seeing. Your terminology and description of your experience does not match my own, and I suspect we’re not talking about the same things. Please clearly specify what your end goal is here also.

Comment: Windows 7 has no feature to “reset” or “refresh” the install.  Your only choice is an in-place upgrade or a full format and reinstall of Eindows 7 both require a Windows 7 ISO see my answer on the subject for more information

Comment: Sorry to be unclear. :

Comment: Step 1 I used the Win7 Backup & Restore tool to create a system restore image to a secondary disk drive. I installed a new and installed Win7.  Step 2 was to create a Win7 installation CD on a USB flash drive.  The PC I'm fixing does not have a working CD/DVD player.  I used Rufus to copy the Win7 CD to the USB flash drive. Step 3 was to boot the computer using the Win7 USB.  Instead of doing an installation, I chose repair.  I selected the Disk Image option and selected the image from my secondary drive.  I get a "Parameter is incorrect" with code 0x80070057.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the conclusion to the saga.  I applied the following solutions and the problem was solved.
1.  I set decimal and added a registry key as per this webpage [Windows backup is unable to start error 0x80070057](https://superuser.com/questions/795099/windows-backup-is-unable-to-start-error-0x80070057)
2.  I requested this hotfix from Microsoft, but didn't need to use it (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2569601/restore-operation-by-using-backup-and-restore-may-fail-in-windows-7-sp
3.  The key clue came from this post ([Why do I get Error 0x80070057 - "The Parameter is Incorrect" when restoring from Windows Backup?](https://superuser.com/questions/607788/why-do-i-get-error-0x80070057-the-parameter-is-incorrect-when-restoring-from)).  I am booting from a USB and so this is a drive with no backup files.  I unplug it as per this post and the restore proceeded without error.
4.  Success!